# Item blocking drawer opening can’t be moved

Tags: stuck

A knife in a knife block inside the drawer is too high and blocking the drawer opening. Because it is a slot in the knife block it can’t be moved back-and-forth or up-and-down so using the wire or something thin doesn’t work.

Comment: If the drawer closed, then the knife _can_ be moved to where the drawer will open. You may need to hold it in that position, but "if it happened, it must be possible."

Comment: is there aa drawer above it

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions

1. If there is a drawer above it, then remove that and try.
2. Maybe the block can be tipped over.
3. Or turn/rotate it quarter turn then try to tip it over.
4. If there are drawers below it, remove them, pull the stuck drawer open, as far as it will go. Then stick you arm behind and up, from below and fiddle with it

Answer (score 0):

I would try shaking/vibrating the drawer, maybe something will settle down.

BTW: If it can't be moved....how did it get in?

Comment: If the knife is sticking out, at an angle,  its a wedge and can go in when pushed/slammed